# How do I use a Gaussian as a window function for a high-pass filter?

Tags: functions, image-processing

I'd like to apply a high-pass filter to some 2D data. Given the diagram on the [documentation page](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighpassFilter.html) for `HighpassFilter`, I assume the default window function is a Dirichlet window (i.e. a unit step, which amounts to no smoothing). I'd like to use a gaussian instead. I know I can do this by simply multiplying the FFT of the data by a gaussian, but I'd like to do it using the in-built `HighpassFilter` function if possible. However, I'm getting an error.

Here's a MWE:

```
data=RandomReal[{0,1},{40,40}];
cutoff=Pi/10;
HighpassFilter[data,cutoff,Automatic,NormalDistribution[]]]
```

The error I get is the following:

> `HighpassFilter::win: "Invalid window type NormalDistribution[0,1]. >>`

Clicking on the link merely directs me to the `HighpassFilter` documentation, which contains a few example window functions and says I can define my own $f$ (which is what I tried to do above).

I tried reducing the data to 1D in case the problem was the gaussian being defined in 1D by default, but I got the same error, so it can't be that.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NormalDistribution[]` is a distribution not a function. You want to use its probability density function:

```
HighpassFilter[data, cutoff, Automatic, PDF[NormalDistribution[]]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. :)